# CSS positionning in mm on A4 page not working right

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

I am struggling to understand why the mm dimension I am giving in CSS to different div are not correct on the html A4 page.

My objective is to use a background image for the A4 and position the text blocks in absolute divs.

Here is the code I am using and you can see the page [here](https://utopia-africa.com/tools/viewSC?id=3).

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <title>Utopia Africa</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/245732172a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <style>  
 html, body { margin:0; font-family:Calibri; color:#858484; }
 .container {
   border:1px solid blue; 
   background-image:url('{{ $page->layout }}');
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-position: center;
   background-size:cover;
   width:210mm;
   height:297mm;
   padding:20mm;
 }
 div, p { font-family:Calibri; color:#858484; }
 .div-edit { border:1px solid green; position:absolute; top:0mm; left:172mm; width:78mm; height:8mm; padding:0; background-color:grey; color:white; text-align:right; }
 .div-edit, .div-edit a, .div-edit a:link, .div-edit a:visited { font-size:0.8em; color:white; }     
 .div-body { border:1px solid red; position:absolute; top:8mm; left:54mm; width:188mm; height:280mm; padding:0; }
 .scTitle { font-family:Calibri; color:#f7a600; font-size:1.8em; padding-top:0mm; padding-right:120mm; }
 .scSubTitle { font-family:Calibri; color:#858484; font-weight:bold; font-size:1em; padding-top:-10mm; padding-right:56mm; }
 .div-link { border:1px solid blue; position:absolute; top:330mm; left:54mm; width:188mm; height:7mm; padding:0; }
 .div-link, .div-link a, .div-link a:link, .div-link a:visited { font-size:0.9em; color:white; }    
 strong, .scStrong { font-weight:bold; color:#f7a600; }
 li::marker { content:"✓  "; color:#f7a600; }
 </style>
 </head>
 
 <div class="container">
     <div class="div-body">
         {!! $page->body !!}
     </div>
     <div class="div-link">
         {!! $page->link !!}
     </div>
 </div>
 </html>
```

You will see that to position the 2 divs, I have to give mm that are bigger than the page size.  What is wrong with my approach?

Comment: Without `box-sizing: border-box` the  rule `.container { padding: 20mm }`  adds to the total width and height of `.container`, making them `210 + 40 = 250mm` and `297 + 40 = 337mm` respectively. You also forgot `.container { position: relative }`...

Comment: @RenevanderLende Thank you for that... I changed that as well as background-size:contain; and it now works perfectly!

Comment: YW, btw, very nice photo site! Takes me places I've never been and probably will never be able to visit. Cudos!

Comment: @RenevanderLende Thank you but which site are you referring to/

Comment: The site you mentioned in your profile...